# shell: remove pattern from file name

Tags: sed

within workdir I have many filles with the names in the following format:

```
7000_grid12_10_lig_cne_767_lig.dlg
```

I need one line sed (or other shell utility) expression suitable to substitute `_grid12_ to _` , so the filename become

```
7000_10_lig_cne_767_lig.dlg
```

I've tried to use rename for all filles but it did not work (verbose found nothing)

```
rename -v 's/_grid12_/_/' *.dlg
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use perl-rename (there is
another program called `rename` which is a part of `util-linux` package):

```
perl-rename 's,_grid12_,_,' *
```

You don't even need a loop as `perl-rename` will rename all files in
the current directory.

Comment: it seems that this script has not been installed on the linux cluster where I handle with the filles :-) -bash: perl-rename: command not found

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I've tried it on MAC as well as on our linux multi-cpu cluster (sorry I don't know what is the OS there ).. this is why I looked for sed sollution, which probably also could be used without loop just via regular expessions..

Comment: Try with simple `rename` instead of `perl-rename`

Comment: already tried using the same syntax but it did not work ..